# Tkinter - Button on new window

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want to add a button in the new window, but I have a doubt about that. Do I do this inside the function, like a did with the label or in a space that I have reserved below, just for the buttons?

Follows the code below:

```
from tkinter import *

ftela = Tk()
ftela.state("zoomed")
ftela.title("OMNIA v0")
menu = Menu(ftela)
ftela.config(menu=menu)

##-----------------##
##   FUNÇÕES/DEF   ##
##-----------------##

def new_window():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.geometry("800x600+275+75")
    newWindow.resizable(height=False, width=False)

    newWindow = LabelFrame(newWindow, text="sex")
    newWindow.place(x=10, y=10, width=675, height=400)

##-----------------##
##     LABELS      ##
##-----------------##

mylabel = LabelFrame(ftela, text="teste")
mylabel.place(x=10, y=10, width=300, height=150)

l_teste = Label(ftela, text="teste")
l_teste.place(x=15, y=30)
e_teste = Entry(ftela)
e_teste.place(x=100, y=30)

##-----------------##
##     SUBMENU     ##
##-----------------##

subMenu1=Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="Cadastro", menu=subMenu1)
subMenu1.add_command(label="Empresas", command=new_window)
subMenu1.add_command(label="Usuários")
subMenu1.add_separator()
subMenu1.add_command(label="Bancos/Caixas")
subMenu1.add_command(label="Contas")

##-----------------##
##     BOTOES      ##    <<< here  **
##-----------------##

bt = Button()
bt.place(x=100, y=100, width=100, height=100)


ftela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add the `Button` in the same function that creates the new window and specify the `newWindow` as its parent. (When any widget is created, a parent-child relationship is created. For example, if you place a text label inside a frame, the frame is the "parent" of the label.)

This would mean doing it something like this:

```
##-----------------##
##   FUNÇÕES/DEF   ##
##-----------------##

def new_window():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.geometry("800x600+275+75")
    newWindow.resizable(height=False, width=False)

    labelFrame = LabelFrame(newWindow, text="sex")
    labelFrame.place(x=10, y=10, width=675, height=400)

    ##-----------------##
    ##     BOTOES      ##
    ##-----------------##
    btn = Button(newWindow, text="My Button")  # HERE
    btn.place(x=100, y=100, width=100, height=100)
```